# "Two and two makes four" vs. "two and two make four"

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, numbers

> 1. Two and two makes four.
> 2. Two and two make four.

Which is grammatical? Please provide your reasoning.

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as ["Equal" versus "Equals"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166173/equal-versus-equals), which has answers and links to two further duplicates.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I know you all just marked this as a duplicate, but I am not satisfied by the duplicate answer.  We use "make" in this instance because "Two and two" forms a compound subject joined by "and".  Compound subjects joined by "and" are always plural; therefore, we use the plural verb "make".

Comment: @AP Have you looked at [the duplicate's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166173/equal-versus-equals) answers? They say the same thing as you; and offer the contrary view too. So it is a duplicate.