# Two two's makes four

Tags: grammaticality

From 1- 3 all are correct.

> 1) Two and two is four.
>
> 2) Two and two make four.
>
> 3) Two two's makes four.

I am confused about the third example .Can anyone explain it?

Comment: The third example should be "Two twos make four" (i.e. no apostrophe).

Comment: #3 is confusing because some authorities hold that if "two" is replaced with "2" then an apostrophe should be used when pluralizing.  Then somewhat less authoritative folks back-apply that rule to "two".

Comment: See the related https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166397/two-and-two-makes-four-vs-two-and-two-make-four (et al.) but it doesn't address the third example

Comment: If you could explain in detail how *Two two's makes four*, most of your problem would vanish.

Comment: Though the (extremely occasional) use of the apostrophe to make plurals is licensed by some (ex's; do's), two's has never been considered correct.

Comment: Blankly asserting correctness does not make a good question. What convinced you of the correctness?

Answer (score 1):

1) Two and two is four. = 2 and 2 is four. [spoken more than written]

The written form is: 2 plus 2 is 4. [arithmetic numbers, formal register]

2) Two and two make four. [informal speech, arithmetic]
"But Little Johnny, two and two make four, not five."

3) Two twos make four. [informal speech, not arithmetic, cards, for example]

Correction: Two twos make four. [plural nouns take a plural verb]

The plural of two is twos, just like threes and fours, etc.

"I have two twos, an ace and two kings." [poker, five cards per hand]
"There are only three fours in this deck. One is missing." [cards]
"How many twos and threes did they put in the mural?" [number two and number three]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer should be deleted but since you ask only to explain third phrase

My understanding  is that the first "two" examples are referencing  addition whereas the third is an explanation that the same result is derived from multiplication but as in all things identical results are sometimes not equal.

The grouping was often said with a humorous air, and is a means to consider

2 plus (lots of) 2 (additive) make (is equal to) 4
2 (times) 2s (multiplied) makes (equals) 4

in addition it can be seen as a foreshortening of a fuller explanation
 two twos makes for ? (thus a pun when said in context)

Answer (score -1):

Singular and plural are both correct.

The singular form is also used because "two and two" is an arithmetic formula. The verb agreement in that case is with the formula as a single entity.

*Two and two makes four.

*Two plus two is four.

*Four times four divided by two is
eight.

In your example in particular, Google indicates that the plural form occurs more often

Comment: You haven't addressed the third example of the question. Additionally the difference between the first two has been discussed here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166397/two-and-two-makes-four-vs-two-and-two-make-four and several other places